# Is the the $n \times n$ matrix $A_{ij} = (ij + 1)^m$, $m \geq n$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Consider the $n \times n$ symmetric matrix A, whose $ij$-th entry is defined by $A_{ij} = (ij + 1)^m$ and $m \geq n$. Is this matrix invertible?

Approaches I've tried:

- Numeric attempts to find a counterexample over a range of $n$ and $m$ have failed. These experiments did suggest that $A$ may be positive definite.
- A unisolvence theorem approach does not work, because the $n$ polynomials defining the rows or columns are of order $m$ and evaluated at $n \leq m$ points.

Comment: When you write counterfactual you mean counterexample.

Comment: Why do you exclude $m=n$? Is there a singular example then?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez fixed.

Comment: @DietrichBurde For $m=n$ I believe its possible to prove via the unisolvence theorem.

Comment: I see. But for the result we could include the case $m=n$.

Comment: Yep! Updated the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ is positive definite (and hence invertible) when $m+1\ge n$. Let $V$ be the $n\times(m+1)$ Vandermonde matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&1^1&1^2&\cdots&1^m\\
1&2^1&2^2&\cdots&2^m\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
1&n^1&n^2&\cdots&n^m}
$$
From binomial expansion, we get $A=VDV^T$, where $D=\operatorname{diag}\left(\binom{m}{0},\binom{m}{1},\ldots,\binom{m}{m}\right)$. Since $D$ is positive definite and $V$ has full row rank (because $m+1\ge n$), $A$ is positive definite.